# android studio more than 15minutes build time

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have just migrated from eclipse and now using android studio for development.
The build time for my app exceeds more than 15 minutes and I don't know why.
This, compared to my previous eclipse build is far far slow.
I don't know if I'm doing this the right way.
I'm using a Dell Inspiron Laptop with intel i3 processor , 4GB RAM .
The memory usage of AS is approx 1100 Mb

I have tried the following:
-> using

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

-> using

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

I'm using 3 support libraries namely appcompat, cardview, design

on running the application, most time is spent doing the task assembleDebug.

I'm not sure if its relevant but I'm using GenyMotion Emulator to debug.

Comment: 15 minutes? how long did it take under eclipse?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a lot of time to sync gradle files, but after that, it should compile faster. You don't need to sync every time.

Comment: @pskink eclipse took less than a minute.A minute at most.

Comment: @heloisasim This build time is after i sync.Sync takes approx 3mins

Comment: Hi, I also have same problem.. Did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

solved it by checking 'Offline work' in 'Global Gradle Settings'.

[image]

There have a problem with enabling this option, while need some updates or downloads for gradle it will show error message.

Thanks...